# Gradle build fails using Jenkins, succeeds manually

Tags: jenkins, gradle, artifactory, maven-central

I'm trying to create a Jenkins task to build my Gradle project.
Cloning the git repo and using the Gradle wrapper of the project works fine.
But when it tries to run the gradle task named `buildProduction`, fails with the following error:

```
Plugin [id: 'com.jfrog.artifactory', version: '4.7.2', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:
- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.jfrog.artifactory:com.jfrog.artifactory.gradle.plugin:4.7.2')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
```

The interesting thing is when I manually run this Gradle task (inside the Jenkins workspace where the repo is cloned) like this:
`gradlew buildProduction` it works perfectly and is able to fetch all the plugins and dependencies.

Comment: This sort of thing is *generally* some kind of path issue, but I'll leave specifics to the gradle-and-Jenkins experts. (Git isn't involved here.)